# Azure B2C Custom policy sign-up not working Error: The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I've deployed started pack b2c custom policies using automated tool. Registered SAML application by following MS guidelines.
I can see B2C login screen with sign-in and Sign-up buttons. However, when I click sign up, getting an strange error "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred." - Please note sign-in function works fine, wondering why sign-up not working its same user journey for both sign-in and sign-up ( - unified?local=signup&csrf_token URL param returns this error.)

Not sure, what settings could possibly gone wrong here? I've successful use cases for other tenant and followed the same exact approach. I greatly appreciate if you can shed some light on this pls. Pls refer the screen-shot below.

[image: Error Message When Selecting Sign Up]

[image: SigninSignup page]

```xml
          <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
          <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
            <Item Key="language.button_continue">Create</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
            <!-- Optional claims, to be collected from the user -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: Share your user journey and technical profiles related to the sign in and sign up steps (step 1+2).

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT This issue has been resolved by changing the base policy claim type id from SigninNames.emailAddress to OtherMails. In this way, both signin and signup works fine. However either of using this claim type id, I am unable to store use sign in email-id to Azure B2C Portal User profile "Contact Info" "email id" field? It always stores Alternate email field only. It would be nice to store this value in the "Email" field.  Can you pls help me on this? Thanks.

Comment: You need to share the technical profiles for sign up, including the one which writes the user.

Comment: Thanks @JasSuri-MSFT, shared the sign up technical profile on the initial post. Thanks again.

Comment: @Karikalan Is this resolved. I am facing the same issue while redirecting, Please guide me if you have an solution. Did you changed signinNames.emailAddress to OtherMails will resolved this issue?

Comment: @NachiappanR Yes, it was resolved. In my case, this issue was temporary and after clearing coookies / history and it worked fine without any error. If this doesn't work you may try debug this using Appinsights. Pls refer: https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/debugging-custom-policy-exceptions-in-azure-ad-b2c-6703f53c4e15

Comment: i am still facing the same error someone can guide me how can i fix it no proper answer is marked and the user didn't answer how he fixed this!